# Ordenar do menor para maior em priority_queue desempatando por segundo elemento, é possível?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Estou estudando `priority_queue` e surgiu uma duvida, caso eu queira inserir na fila de prioridade um par de elementos, como faço para que a fila mostra o elemento com menor numero e se tiver dois números iguais ele desempate pelo segundo identificador?

Ex: Quero inserir na fila os elementos identificados por (i,j): (5,1) (3,2) (6,3) (3,4)

Eu queria que minha fila de prioridade retornasse sempre o menor elemento i e caso tenha dois elementos i iguais, desempatasse pelo segundo elemento que é o j

Saída:

```
(3,2)
(3,4)
(5,1)
(6,3)
```

Obs: Nunca irá existir um j igual

Alguém tem alguma dica ? tentei por `pair`, mas não estou sabendo fazer corretamente

Comment: O que é inserido na `queue` ? Esses valores fazem parte de alguma classe ou estrutura ? Tem como colocar o código que está a usar ?

Comment: Na queue é inserido um pair<int,int>, os valores não fazem parte de uma estrutura.
Eu não tenho o código, pois estou criando ainda, como surgiu essa duvida, eu travei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possivel de controlar a forma como os elementos são colocados numa `priority_queue` se utilizar uma função personalizada no terceiro parametro de template. Essa função tem de ser fornecida por meio do operador `()` de uma classe ou através de uma função solta utilizando `std::function` que é o exemplo eu vou seguir.

A função que compara os dois pontos é que vai fazer a lógica que indicou de quando os dois `i` forem iguais comparar pelo `j`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>

typedef std::pair<int, int> parInts;

bool comparador (parInts ponto1, parInts ponto2){
    if (ponto1.first == ponto2.first){ //se o i é igual compara pelo j
        return ponto1.second > ponto2.second;
    }
    else { //se o i é diferente compara por esse i
        return ponto1.first > ponto2.first;
    }
}
```

Fiz uso de um  `typedef` para simplificar um pouco o tipo e a criação da `priority_queue` que vem agora a seguir.

A utilização no `main` seria da seguinte forma:

```
int main () {
    std::priority_queue<parInts, std::vector<parInts>, std::function<bool(parInts, parInts)>> fila(comparador);
    //                   ^--tipo        ^--contentor              ^--tipo do comparador            ^--comparador

    fila.push(std::make_pair(5, 1));
    fila.push(std::make_pair(3, 2));
    fila.push(std::make_pair(6, 3));
    fila.push(std::make_pair(3, 4));

    while (!fila.empty()){
        std::pair<int, int> ponto = fila.top();
        std::cout << ponto.first << " " << ponto.second << std::endl;
        fila.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A fila foi criada com 3 parametros do template:

1. O tipo
2. O contentor onde serão colocados os elementos
3. O tipo do comparador

O tipo do comparador foi definido como:

```
std::function<bool(parInts, parInts)>
```

Que seria equivalente a ter escrito:

```
std::function<bool(std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>)>
```

Ainda na mesma instrução o comparador é passado na construção, no fim:

```
... std::function<bool(parInts, parInts)>> fila(comparador);
//                                                ^-- aqui
```

O resultado obtido:

```
3 2
3 4
5 1
6 3
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/UfaWy8)

Comment: Muito obrigado !!

Comment: Usar `std::function` aqui não tem vantagem alguma sobre usar um functor.